ERC-4337 Account Abstraction
This is the smart contract which is provided by alchemy
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "@account-abstraction/contracts/core/EntryPoint.sol";
import "@account-abstraction/contracts/interfaces/IAccount.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Create2.sol";



contract Account is IAccount{
    uint public count;
    address public owner;
    constructor (address _owner) {
       owner= _owner;
    }

    function validateUserOp(UserOperation calldata userOp , bytes32 userOpHash , uint256 )
    external view returns (uint256 validationData) 
    {
      
      return 0; 
    }
    function execute() external{
        count++;
    }
}
    contract AccountFactory{
    function createAccount(address owner) external returns (address){
      Account acc= new Account(owner);
      return address(acc);
    }
    }

and this is the ethers.js 6 version of that code
const hre = require("hardhat");
const AF_Address= "0x40220563ac2100E5D142919be1B11D2975728b15";
const FNonce= 1;
const EP_Address= "0xd4719545ED60F8ea78CE31cF75d45f49C4B1ADAF";
const PM_Address= "0x314E75ab054564ba4b201d7084C94D07058e2B48";

async function main() {
  const entryPoint = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("EntryPoint", EP_Address);
  const sender= await hre.ethers.getCreateAddress({
    from:AF_Address,
    nonce: FNonce
  })
  console.log("The sender Address is: ", sender);

  const AccountFactory= await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("AccountFactory");
  const[signer0]= await hre.ethers.getSigners();
  const address0= await signer0.getAddress();
  const initCode = AF_Address + AccountFactory.interface.encodeFunctionData("createAccount",[address0]).slice(2); 

const Account= await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Account");

await entryPoint.depositTo(PM_Address,{
   value: hre.ethers.parseEther("0.01")
});


const userOp = { 
   
         sender, 
         nonce: await entryPoint.getNonce(sender,0), 
         initCode,
         callData: Account.interface.encodeFunctionData("execute"),  
         callGasLimit: 400000,
         verificationGasLimit:400000,
         preVerificationGas:70000 ,
         maxFeePerGas: hre.ethers.parseUnits("10","gwei"),
         maxPriorityFeePerGas:hre.ethers.parseUnits("10","gwei"),
         paymasterAndData: PM_Address,
         signature: "0x"
    
}

const tx= await entryPoint.handleOps([userOp], address0);
const receipt= await tx.wait();
console.log(receipt);
}
main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
     process.exitCode = 1;
    });

This code works fine where count is rising whenever I run this code and Pay Master is paying for this transaction. callData: Account.interface.encodeFunctionData("execute") here callData does not have any Parameter and it works well
Note :- When I try to make the same code work by adding my smart contract logic where my function consist of one parameter of functionName(bytes32[] calldata)
callData:Account.interface.encodeFunctionData("FunctionName", [[ethers.encodeBytes32String("String")]]),
its showing provider error - execution reverted
This is my code in ethers.js 6 version
const hre = require("hardhat");
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const AF_Address = "0x2fd4ee9d606B47Caa066b5184E09E7b643f75930"; // AccountFactory2 Address
const FNonce = 1;
const EP_Address = "0x8CE61D5800346EB420906c71C3d040F84BA9d2Fb"; // EntryPoint Address
const PM_Address = "0x314E75ab054564ba4b201d7084C94D07058e2B48"; // PayMaster Address


async function main() {
    const entryPoint = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("EntryPoint", EP_Address);
    const sender = await hre.ethers.getCreateAddress({ //getCreateAddress takes from: address, nonce as input
        from: AF_Address,
        nonce: FNonce,
    });

    console.log("The sender Address is: ", sender);

    const AccountFactory = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("AccountFactory2");
    const [signer0] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();
    const address0 = await signer0.getAddress();
    const initCode = AF_Address + AccountFactory.interface.encodeFunctionData("createAccount", [address0]).slice(2);

    const Account = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("ContractName");
    
    
    const userOp = {
        sender, 
        nonce: await entryPoint.getNonce(sender, 0),
        initCode, 
        callData:Account.interface.encodeFunctionData("FunctionName", [[ethers.encodeBytes32String("String")]]),  
        callGasLimit: 400000, 
        verificationGasLimit: 400000,
        preVerificationGas: 70000,
        maxFeePerGas: hre.ethers.parseUnits("10", "gwei"), 
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: hre.ethers.parseUnits("10", "gwei"),
        paymasterAndData: PM_Address,
        signature: "0x" 
    };

    
    const tx = await entryPoint.handleOps([userOp], address0);
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log(receipt);


  

   // console.log("Account Balance", await hre.ethers.provider.getBalance(sender_address));
    //const EP = await hre.ethers.getContractAt("EntryPoint", EP_Address);
    //console.log("EntryPoint Balance", await EP.balanceOf(sender_address));
    //console.log("PayMaster Balance", await EP.balanceOf(PM_Address));
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});

"ProviderError: execution reverted
at HttpProvider.request (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\providers\http.js:84:27)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async HardhatEthersProvider.estimateGas (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\internal\hardhat-ethers-provider.js:122:31)
at async C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\signers.js:183:43
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async HardhatEthersSigner._sendUncheckedTransaction (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\signers.js:199:13)
at async HardhatEthersSigner.sendTransaction (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules@nomicfoundation\hardhat-ethers\signers.js:108:22)
at async send (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:228:20)
at async Proxy.handleOps (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\node_modules\ethers\lib.commonjs\contract\contract.js:261:16)
at async main (C:\Users\psaik\Desktop\AA2\scripts\execute2.js:44:11)"
I tried to add the input string into the blockchain but its showing an error
